# Prove $\bigcup \omega_1 = \omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

This is a question regarding ordinals and probably requires some background knowledge of ordinal arithmetic. I will list what I hope is the relevant information for this question:

$\omega_1$ is defined to be the first uncountable ordinal. Therefore any ordinal $\alpha < \omega_1$ is countable. The fact $\bigcup \omega_1 = \omega_1$ is supposed to be used to be able to prove the definition of $\omega_1$, so the only things we are allowed to take for granted are: (1) $\omega_1$ is a set; (2) $\omega_1$ is an ordinal; (3) $\omega_1$ is uncountable. So at this stage, we are $\textbf{not}$ allowed to assume that $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal.

In general (although I do not know if this applies to $\omega_1$), if $A$ is a proper subset of $X$ then the union of set $X$ of sets is $\bigcup A = \{x : x \in A \, \mbox{for} \, A \in X \} = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_n$.

I'm not very sure how to start this proof so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with $\omega_1$. What you should prove instead is that if $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal, $\alpha=\beta+1$, then $\bigcup\alpha=\beta$, and oherwise $\bigcup\alpha=\alpha$.

Comment: You have three sorts of ordinals: $0$ (unique), successors $\alpha+1$ and limits. An ordinal $\alpha$ is a limit if and only if $\alpha=\cup \alpha$

Comment: @drhab: $\bigcup0=0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. Uptil now I didn't realize that. My learning never comes to an end.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6):

It is in fact true that for every limit ordinal, countable or otherwise, that $\bigcup\alpha=\alpha$.

So it would suffice to prove that $\omega_1$ is a limit ordinal. This is true because if $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal then we can define a bijection between $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$. So if $\omega_1$ is $\alpha+1$ we have that $|\alpha|=|\omega_1|$ and so $\omega_1$ cannot be the least uncountable ordinals.

---

Finally, why does it hold $\bigcup\alpha=\alpha$ for limit ordinals? Note that if $\gamma<\alpha$ then $\gamma+1<\alpha$, therefore $\gamma\in\gamma+1$ so $\gamma\in\bigcup\alpha$. So $\alpha\subseteq\bigcup\alpha$. The other direction is even simpler.

Comment: To prove $\omega_1$ is a limit ordinal, would I just need to prove that $\omega_1$ is not a successor ordinal? (and obviously that $\omega_1$ is not $0$.

Comment: That is correct.